# How to explain why the angle between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined the way it is.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

It is given in couple of the textbooks I have seen that they just define the angle between two vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be $\theta$ such that 
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} }{ \|\vec{x}\| \|\vec{y}\|}.
$$ 
I wanted to explain this to a first year undergraduate student why this makes some sense and that it is not completely arbitrary, but I wasn't really sure how to do so. I would greatly appreciate any explanation! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula matches the traditional geometric notion of the angle between two vectors if they are in $\Bbb R^2$ (with standard scalar product), which is especially easy to see if $\|\vec x\|=\|\vec y\|=1$ and even more specifically $\vec x={1\choose 0}$ and $\vec y={\cos x\choose \sin x}$. For higher dimensions, we can reduce to the $\Bbb R^2$ situation by considereing the space spanned by $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not quite seeing how to reduce to the $\mathbb{R}$^2 case from higher dimension... Could you possibly do an example of a $3$ dim case by any chance?

Comment: I guess what I am confused with is that: I see what is happening in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I see that for higher dimensions the two vectors span a plane so one can "reduce" to the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I am just not seeing how the dot product of these two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ corresponds to the dot product of these two vectors view as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: @JohnnyT. One thing you need to know is that an isometry preserves the scalar product. Isometries can be generated by a sequence of reflections, so you simply have to prove it for a reflection (you can do a translation separately, and that might help - it is easy to see that the scalar product is invariant under translation). Then you can use an isometry to move one vector to a convenient axis and the other to a convenient plane containing that axis. Then you are down to two dimensions.

Comment: @MarkBennet I see it now! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

We can fit our vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ into a triangle

[image: hello]

The [law of cosines](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att12/derivelawofsines.htm) says

$$
\left\lVert\vec y-\vec x\right\rVert^2
= \left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert^2+\left\lVert \vec y\right\rVert^2
-2\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert\left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert\cos\theta\tag{1}
$$

But we also have
$$
\left\lVert\vec y-\vec x\right\rVert^2
= \left(\vec y-\vec x\right)\cdot \left(\vec y-\vec x\right)
= \vec y\cdot\vec y+\vec x\cdot\vec x-2\,\vec x\cdot\vec y
= \left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert^2+\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert^2-2\,\vec x\cdot\vec y\tag{2}
$$
Plugging (2) into (1) gives
$$
\left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert^2+\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert^2-2\,\vec x\cdot\vec y=\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert^2+\left\lVert \vec y\right\rVert^2
-2\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert\left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert\cos\theta
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\vec x\cdot\vec y=\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert\left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert\cos\theta
$$
Thus $\cos\theta$ can be expressed as
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{\vec x\cdot\vec y}{\left\lVert\vec x\right\rVert\left\lVert\vec y\right\rVert}
$$
as desired!

In other words, taking this equation as the definition of $\cos\theta$ matches our intuition developed in trigonometry.